# tsconfig.json not used by TypeScript compiler?

Tags: typescript, reference, tsconfig

I'm new to TypeScript. I am trying to setup the use of it in WebStorm.
I have created a tsconfig.json file in the root of my project and changed the builtin ts compiler to version 1.6.2. 
Still I need to include reference paths in every ts file. I hoped this would not be needed anymore once I defined the tsconfig.json file.

I tried to isolate the issue and went testing outside WebStorm. The issue remains.
This is my setup:
I installed TypeScript with "npm install -g typescript".
I created a folder with this structure:

```
test\
  tsconfig.json
  src\
     file1.ts
     file2.ts
```

file2.ts uses a Class which is created in file1.ts.

When I run "tsc file2.ts" inside the src folder, I get a:

```
C:\data\tryout\tsconfig\src\file2.ts(11,20): error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'TodoCtrl'.
```

What do I need to do to get the compiler find all ts files automatically?

file1.ts:

```
module todos {
    'use strict';

    export class TodoCtrl {
        constructor() { }

        onTodos() {
                console.log('ok');
        }
    }
}
```

file2.ts:

```
// does work with ///<reference path='file1.ts' />
module todos {
    'use strict';

    export class DoneCtrl {
        constructor() { }

        onDone() {
            var test = new TodoCtrl();
        }
    }
}
```

result:

```
error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'TodoCtrl'.
```

I have put everything in a zip:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o4x52rddanhjqnr/tsconfig.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

Running `tsc src\file2.ts` will only use `src\file2.ts` as the input.

Run `tsc` in the directory with no input files for it to use the `tsconfig.json`, and input all `.ts` files in the directory and subdirectories.

As for why `tsc src\file2.ts` doesn't work. Your reference was missing a slash.

`// <reference path='file1.ts' />`

should be:

`/// <reference path='file1.ts' />`

Comment: I used // to put the reference in comment. It works with the reference, but I do not want to use references.

Comment: If I issue tsc in the source folder without any arguments, I just get the usage info for tsc. Nothing is compiled.

Comment: I downloaded your ZIP. There were only two slashes in there.

Comment: Run `tsc -v`. I'm guessing that it's an older `tsc.exe` you're calling, and not `tsc.cmd` from npm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will be relevant to your work but your zip contains an empty tsconfig.json.
I filled it in with some options and actually was able to compile, both from the command line and from the editor.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "outDir": ".",
        "sourceMap": false
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./src/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

I hope this leads you somewhere.